# Programmatically trigger a SageMaker's Notebook instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

So to start with, I currently have a system on AWS that does the following

1. Collects user data (consent is assumed of course) and store it in an S3 bucket
2. Uses Sagemaker notebook instance to train on the user data and deploys an endpoint. The endpoint is later invoked by a lambda function (I followed this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-aws-sagemakers-linear-learner-to-solve-regression-problems-36732d802ba6))

The problem is, I have to

1. manually run the notebook instance
2. manually change the path for each user's data

What I would like to do,

#### First:

- Trigger the notebook instance programmatically.
- This can be periodically or through an event. I could call the notebook instance from a lambda function or another AWS service.

#### Second:

- Pass an argument to the notebook instance (e.g., bucket path where
  data is stored)

#### Approach

##### Notebook Jobs

I found some resources that suggested Notebook jobs. However, notebook jobs only give the ability to schedule notebooks.

There is an option to send parameters (which I was not able to get to work), but that option just means you pass the same argument on every run.

My question is this, am I following the right approach? Or is there something else I should consider?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to start the notebook instance, or run the notebook? If it's the latter, notebook jobs are the best way, with parameterized executions, and you can run them on a schedule (but agree that the job will have a default parameter that you specify when creating the job schedule). Otherwise, you can execute your NB at startup like this - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/execute-notebook-on-startup/on-start.sh. Have you considered training jobs instead of notebooks?

Comment: I just looked at training jobs, thanks. It seems promising but I only found official documentations for it (like this one: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_training_job). I could not find any examples though. As far as I understand, you can create a training job using python's SDK (or other SDK) which means I can write a lambda function that starts a training job. Is that correct?

Comment: https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/advanced_functionality should have a lot more examples. Yes, you can definitely trigger the job from a Lambda function, and can parameterize based on the Lambda input event.

Answer (score 1):

Passing arguments or parameters to the SageMaker notebook instance can be achieved in several ways:

- Parameterized Notebooks
- Environment Variables
  Parametrized notebooks need several programming tricks to parse the arguments but environment variables are much easier. Here is a code snippet for this one

`

```
import boto3
sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

# Define the notebook instance name
notebook_instance_name = 'your-notebook-instance-name'

# Define the environment variables as key-value pairs
environment_variables = {
'S3_BUCKET_PATH': 's3://your-bucket-name/path-to-data',
'OTHER_CONFIG_VAR': 'config-value'
}

# Set the environment variables for the notebook instance
sagemaker_client.update_notebook_instance(
NotebookInstanceName=notebook_instance_name,
Environment={
    'Variables': environment_variables
}
)
```

`
Now you can run the notebook

```
    # Start the notebook instance (if it's not already running)


    sagemaker_client.start_notebook_instance(
    NotebookInstanceName=notebook_instance_name)
```

Inside the notebook you now can read the environment variable

```
import os

# Access environment variables
s3_bucket_path = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET_PATH')
other_config_var = os.environ.get('OTHER_CONFIG_VAR')

print("S3 Bucket Path:", s3_bucket_path)
print("Other Configuration Variable:", other_config_var)
```